# ESP32-S3 BLE multiple servers connect to one client at a time

Tags: esp32, bluetooth-low-energy, server, multiple

I am working with ESP32-S3 module on Arduino IDE.I need to connect to multiple BLE servers to one client and able send and receive data from client to all servers at a time. I tried connecting multiple servers to client but they are not connecting at a time so I can't able to send data from client to all servers at a time. Is there any way I can able to connect to connect multiple servers to one client. Please advice to me on this. Please share the resource links if available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your client code allow for more than one connection? From what you describe, I suspect not.

Comment: I can able to connect two servers with my client code but not at a time. Whichever server available my client connects to that server if both available also my client connects to one server and disconnects form that server again starts scanning for server.

Comment: With my client code I can able to connect to two servers but problem is                      
case1:  if client connects to server1 its continuously in connection with server1 its not scanning again for other server. if client connects to server2 its continuously in connection with server2 its not scanning again for other server.                                                         case2:if client connects to server its automatically goes to scan the other devices without printing the all the sensor data.